# AJAX returns status code 0? CORS allowed. Is this AJAX implemented incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a browser action I've implemented it as an AddOn.
I'm testing my construction of the AddOn within my domain
between two machines as server and a client.

I'm stuck at AJAX failing with status code 0.

I set up Apache to enable CORS to make sure that the code is behaving as expected.
I added this line to the apache config and enabled `headers`:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

The javascript code: **UPDATED**

```
function sendData(data){
    var requestdata = 'data1=one&data2=two&data3=three';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST","http://server/test/test.php");

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onloadstart = function(){
    console.log("Onload status: " + xhr.status);
}

xhr.onerror = function(ev) {
    console.log("OnError Status: " + xhr.status + ", Loaded: " + ev.loaded + ", Total: " + ev.total);   
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    if (xhr.status !== 200){
        console.log("Failure :(  + Status: " + xhr.status);
        //console.log(requestdata);
        console.log("Ready State: " + xhr.readyState + ", Status: " + xhr.status +", Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        alert("Success!");
    }
}
    xhr.send(requestdata);
}
```

test.php

```
<?php 
    require '../lib/Database.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db = new Database('test');
    var_dump($db);

    json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Have I done this AJAX implementation correctly?
If I have, and I have made adjustments for CORS, why is it failing with status code 0?

**UPDATE**

This is an AddOn I am testing in Firefox.
From the "matches" parameter in manifest.json, navigating to the page in question retrieves data from the page using Vanilla JS on the DOM.

The collected data is held in an object.

The data object is delivered

This is a picture of what's returned in the browser:
[image]

**UPDATE2**

I replaced the POST url with http://httpbin.org/post to see if the data is going anywhere. Nope.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196448/discussion-on-question-by-ken-ingram-ajax-returns-status-code-0-cors-allowed-i).